# Unable to display SQLite data as listview using phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

The function `get_list()` here is able to execute the query but not able to display the rows.

```
function get_list()
{
    db = window.openDatabase("timeDB", "1.0", "time", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);   

    function populateDB(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT (date) FROM time", [], function (tx, res)
        {            
            var len = result.rows.length;

            if (len > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    var a = results.rows.item(i)['date'];
                    document.getElementById("output").value = a;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function transaction_error(tx, error)
    {
        alert("Database Error: " + error);
    }

    function populateDB_success()
    {
        alert("Successfully inserted");
    }
}
```

The function `get_list()` is working when the code to display the rows is removed. I have already looked through other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake: you used `result` instead of `res`:

```
    tx.executeSql("SELECT (date) FROM time", [], function (tx, res)
    {            
        var len = result.rows.length; // <- should be res

        if (len > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                var a = results.rows.item(i)['date']; // <- should be res
                document.getElementById("output").value = a;
            }
        }
    });
```